# WP ajax function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm encountering a 400 error when making an AJAX call in my project. I know this is asked many times, but I can't figure out my problem.

Here's my JavaScript code:

```
function uploadFile() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajax.url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'action': 'excel_converter',
            'id': 'test'
        },
        processData: false,
        success: function(response){
            console.log('response', response);
        }
    });
}

jQuery(() => {
    const converter = jQuery('.js-excel-converter');
    if(converter) {
        converter.on('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            uploadFile();
        });
    }
});
```

And here's my PHP code (in functions.php):

```
function excel_converter() {
    echo 'hi';
    die('test');
}

function my_script_enqueuer() {
    $manifest = json_decode(file_get_contents(get_template_directory() . '/dist/rev-manifest.json'), true);
    $jsFile = $manifest['app.bundle.full.js'];

    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/scripts/' . $jsFile, array('jquery') );

    // You can now use ajax.url as the URL in your ajax calls
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-js', 'ajax', array(
        'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
    ));

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_excel_converter', 'excel_converter' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_excel_converter', 'excel_converter' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_script_enqueuer' );
```

The php code seems to work fine, because I can use the ajax.url as my Post url.
But for some reason I keep getting a 400 with request url http://localhost:3000/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php. I tried it with my local domain, but same result; http://mysite.test/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

### EDIT

"I tried to put up a simplified version of my problem. This is my actual code:

```
function uploadFile() {
    const messageDiv = jQuery('.js-message')[0];
    jQuery(messageDiv).removeClass('error');
    jQuery(messageDiv).empty('error');

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajax.url,
        type: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        data: {
            'action': 'excel_converter',
            'file': jQuery('#excelFile')[0].files[0],
            'addressColumn': jQuery('#addressColumn').val(),
            'cityColumn': jQuery('#cityColumn').val(),
            'postcodeColumn': jQuery('#postcodeColumn').val(),
            'countryColumn': jQuery('#countryColumn').val(),
            'latitudeColumn': jQuery('#latitudeColumn').val(),
            'longitudeColumn': jQuery('#longitudeColumn').val()
        },
        success: (response) => {
            messageDiv.append(response);
        },
        error: (xhr, status, error) => {
            jQuery(messageDiv).addClass('error');
            messageDiv.append(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}

jQuery(() => {
    const converter = jQuery('.js-excel-converter');
    if(converter) {
        converter.on('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            uploadFile();
        });
    }
});
```

Because I have a file input field, I have to set processData to false. But when I set processData to false, the AJAX function doesn't work in Wordpress anymore; then I get a `400` response."

Answer (score 1):

Putting `processData` as `false` prevents your data from being converted to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, without this conversion wordpress will not know the `action` to take for your ajax request.

Remove `processData: false,` in your ajax call.

### Edit

To upload a file with $.ajax you have to use a FormData object and set `processData` and `contentType` to false.

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('action', 'excel_converter');
fd.append('file', jQuery('#excelFile')[0].files[0]);
fd.append('addressColumn', jQuery('#addressColumn').val());
fd.append('cityColumn', jQuery('#cityColumn').val());
fd.append('postcodeColumn', jQuery('#postcodeColumn').val());
fd.append('countryColumn', jQuery('#countryColumn').val());
fd.append('latitudeColumn', jQuery('#latitudeColumn').val());
fd.append('longitudeColumn', jQuery('#longitudeColumn').val();

jQuery.ajax({
    url: ajax.url,
    type: 'POST',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: fd,
    success: (response) => {
        messageDiv.append(response);
    },
    error: (xhr, status, error) => {
        jQuery(messageDiv).addClass('error');
        messageDiv.append(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Wauw, how could I've missed that? Thanks!

Comment: I actually found out I need the "processData: false". Otherwise I'll receive a "Illegal invocation", I guess because jQuery tries to transform my FormData object to a string.

Comment: There is no FormData in your post